# Downloads get stuck

Tags: downloads

For some reason my downloads get stuck and I have no idea why. The upper-right corner icon shows that I am connected to the internet and web pages load normally, but when I try to install something, from Ubuntu Software Center or download anything from the internet, it downloads normally for some time and then gets stuck and says that download speed is "0 kt/s". So, any suggestions on what I should do?

Comment: Check you Internet speed at http://speedtest.net/Speedtest.net

Comment: Maybe you are installing packages from synaptic and USC simultaneously , which does not work , since they both access the same database of packages . Try installing from one source ( Ubuntu Software center , Synaptic or from Terminal) at a given time .Please close Synaptic if you are using USC for installing , since it waits for System lock to be released by synaptic.Only one source at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Set best server in software center.

Lets see how we can set the best download server for the Ubuntu system, first of all go to `System  > Administration > Software Sources.` The Software Sources dialogue box will be displayed.

[image]

Now you will see that in the above dialogue box the Server for United States is set as the default download server. You can change this server to the one which best suits you. Click the `Download from:` drop down button and choose `Other`.

[image]

Here you will see list of all available ubuntu servers in the Choose a Download Server dialogue box, now click the `Select Best Server` button to select the one which best suits you according to your location.

[image]

It will test all servers by pinging them and upon the basis of the ping results it will suggest to you the best download server.

[image]

This is dramatically increase your download speed. Enjoy!